# IsEqualToString fails every time

Tags: objective-c

I know this is not the most secure way but It is just a starter app, So I use the `ifEqualToString` and it is just going to the else statement. Please help. I even copied and pasted the password and it still marks it incorrect.

here is my 
ViewController.H

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)enterPassword:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"testOne");
    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1234"];

    if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString: passwordString]) {
        // Password is correct
        NSLog(@"Password Correct");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Correct Password" message:@"This password is correct." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else {
        // Password is incorrect
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect Password" message:@"This password is incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"try Again" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"password Incorrect");
    }
}
@end
```

thanks again!!

Comment: Have you debugged whats in passwordField.text?

Comment: Did you link the iVar passwordField to xib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have not linked your passwordField in interface builder.

Comment: how do you link the passwordField in the interface builder?

Comment: @DawsonSeibold https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingOutlet.html

Comment: @DawsonSeibold then you can accept my answer, if your reputation allows it.

Comment: No sorry I cant I don't have the reputation to do it. :(